# A simple question about rational numbers without a simple proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, rational-numbers, axioms, quasigroups

[As in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390676/a-familiar-quasigroup-about-independent-axioms), study the quasigroup $(Q_+,/)$ of positive rational numbers under division. There are two obvious identities:

1. $a/(b/c)=c/(b/a)$, for all $a,b,c\in Q_+$
2. $(a/b)/c=(a/c)/b$, for all $a,b,c\in Q_+$

How to decide if there are other independent identities, not possible to derive?

Could there be "mystical" identities of great complexity including several variables which are independent of 1 and 2?

The only way to go, as I can see, is to study equivalence classes of binary trees corresponding to expressions in $(Q_+,/)$.

Comment: The Knuth-Bendix algorithm can decide this.

Comment: @MYUSERNAMEISALIE: Thanks for the comment, which seems adequate.

Comment: How would you derive $(ab)/(cb)=a/c$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: The expressions are supposed to consists of variables, / and matching brackets only. No multiplication.

Comment: @Lehs Can you derive $a/(b/b)=a$, then? Or $a/a=b/b$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I suppose not, so this might be an other identity then. What I'm wondering about is maximal sets of independent identities and the way to decide which those sets are.

Comment: One of the questions I've answered singles out an element $1$ and has axioms $a/b=1$  If and only if $a=b$ and $(a/c)/(b/c)=a/b$ for all $a,b,c$, and the goal is to prove that the operation $a\cdot b=a/(1/b)$ satisfies all of the axioms for a group.

Comment: (the hard part is proving that $a/1=a$ for all $a$, which indeed holds.)

Comment: @MattSamuel, can youderive that from 1&2?

Comment: @Lehs I can't tell you for sure, but looking at the axioms makes me think it's highly unlikely. In my example the identity is singled out explicitly.